# Improving loop over 4 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, save

I am trying to perform the following loop:
I have three arrays:
l, val_lambda, val_alpha, each of them contains 10 values
and a datasets, a list of 1000 class results, i.e dataset[i] = traj_analysis(dt, X, Y, x, y, z) for x, y, z in l, val_lambda, val_alpha.

Now I would like to print on a file one of the instance's result of the class traj_analysis - with a certain concern for the folders. This is what I wrote down:

```
the_vals = [(x, y, z) for x in val_lambda for y in val_alpha for z in l]
for (x, y, z) in tqdm(the_vals):
    for data in datasets:
        if x == data.par_lambda & y == data.par_alpha & z == data.l0:
            filename_msd = './simulation/lamda =' +str(f'{x:.2f}')+'/ alpha ='+str(f'{y:.2f}')+'/cargo/l0='+str(f'{z:.2f}')+'/cargo_msd.csv'
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename_msd), exist_ok=True)
            np.savetxt(filename_msd, data.msd, delimiter=',')
```

Unfortunately I got this error:

> ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Can someone help me to reformulate the loop in a coherent way and maybe also to speed it up?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if x == data.par_lambda and y == data.par_alpha and z == data.l0:`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Consider using zip instead,

```
for (x, y, z) in tqdm(zip(val_lambda, val_alpha, l)):
```

Secondly, the issue could be in your `if` statement logic.

This is because `&` has higher precedence over `==`, so in your statement, it might have been evaluated as:

```
if x == (data.par_lambda & y) == (data.par_alpha & z) == data.l0:
```

The fix would be to put the appropriate bracket at the appropriate places:

```
if (x == data.par_lambda) & (y == data.par_alpha) & (z == data.l0):
```

Just to add on, `&` is more commonly used for bitwise operations, hence, as fferri suggested, you might want to change it to `and` instead. The `and` operator has lower precedence over `==`, thus `==` will be evaluted first. Nonetheless, it's still good practice to have the brackets!

```
if (x == data.par_lambda) and (y == data.par_alpha) and (z == data.l0):
```